# Como realizar sobrecarga de métodos com PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, método, sobrecarga

Como realizar sobrecarga de métodos com PHP?

Para poder declarar métodos com o mesmo nome mas com parâmetros diferentes.

Comment: Não existe sobrecarga de métodos em PHP, somente sobrescrita.

Comment: O PHP não tem sobrecarga. Tem apenas os jeitinhos gambiarras de simular

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PHP é uma linguagem dinâmica, portanto isto não faz sentido.

Até existe um conceito chamado [*overloading*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) mas que é um pouco diferente do que você está pensando, mas consegue resultado semelhante.

Em linguagens dinâmicas os parâmetros podem receber qualquer tipo então a resolução do que fazer com eles deve ser dado em tempo de execução através de seleção (`if`, `switch`, elemento de *array* ou outra forma).

Se realmente quer ter métodos que fazem quase a mesma coisa com parâmetros diferentes tem que trocar o nome. Mas o mais comum é que um método faça mais de uma coisa baseado no parâmetro. É, eu sei, para quem está acostumado com tudo organizado em funções únicas parece estranho mas muitas vezes fica até interessante e poupa código.

Normalmente costuma-se dizer que um parâmetro é do tipo [*mixed*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php). Este tipo não existe de fato, é apenas um indicativo que pode-se usar mais de um tipo de dado ali. Exemplo:

```
mixed str_replace(mixed $search, mixed $replace, mixed $subject[, int &$count])
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/Mixed.php).

A função mostra que é possível enviar parâmetros com tipos variados e o retorno da função também pode variar. Pode parecer uma bagunça mas simplifica o uso da linguagem permitindo que uma função realize a tarefa de várias maneiras diferentes. Evidentemente que os erros só podem ser verificados em tempo de execução.

Cada um com suas vantagens e desvantagens.

Answer (score 6):

Como já dito anteriormente, não existe sobrecarga de métodos no PHP.

O que pode ser feito é utilizar os argumentos das funções de maneiras dinâmicas, como já vi em alguns frameworks, como CakePHP e Laravel 4.

Exemplo:

```
<?php


class MyClass{

    protected $values = array();

    function value()
    {
       $count = func_num_args();

       // obtém dados
       if ($count == 1) {

            $key = func_get_arg(0);

            return $this->values[$key];
       }

       // define dados
       if ($count == 2) {

            list($key, $value) = func_get_args();

            $this->values[$key] = $value;

            return $this;
       }

    }
}


$class = new MyClass;

$class->value('key', 'stackoverflow português');

echo $class->value('key'); // Stackoverflow português

print_r($class);
```

Ou seja, através das funções `func_get_arg`, `func_get_args` e `func_num_args`, você pode acessar os argumentos passados nas funções, muito embora os mesmos não sejam previamente declarados na criação da função (no meu exemplo, não há argumentos na declaração do método `MyClass::value`).

No PHP 5.6, temos um bom recurso no PHP chamado de [`Variadic Function`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

Ao invés de usar as três funções que pegam os argumentos citados, apenas utilizamos o operador `...`.

Exemplo refatorado para o PHP 5.6:

```
class MyClass{

    protected $values = array();

    function value(...$args)
    {
       $count = count($args);

       // obtém dados
       if ($count == 1) {

            $key = $args[0];

            return $this->values[$key];
       }

       // define dados
       if ($count == 2) {

            list($key, $value) = $args;

            $this->values[$key] = $value;

            return $this;
       }

    }
}
```

Ao meu ver, a dificuldade de se implementar isso seria documentar o código do seu método ou função.

Teste esses códigos no [PHPSandBox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)